# Standard breaks with limits in ggplot2 axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

What I want is quite simple, yet hard to implement: Set ticks where `ggplot2()` would set them, and additionally at the limits. Since I am dealing with many datasets, I want to avoid setting the ticks on my own.

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=ChickWeight, aes(ChickWeight$Time)) geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
```

In order to add `max(ChickWeight$Time)` to the axis, I have tried `pretty()`, which goes beyond the maximum:

```
ggplot(data=ChickWeight, aes(ChickWeight$Time)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
 + scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty(ChickWeight$Time))
```

...as well as `pretty_breaks()`, which makes even less breaks:

```
require(scales)
ggplot(data=ChickWeight, aes(ChickWeight$Time)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)
 + scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(ChickWeight$Time))
```

But none of the solutions takes any argument that looks like maximum. My maximum values are however something special, which is why I want to include it in the plot.

Comment: Why not just add a vline? You can make it look very similar to a tic, if not identical.

Comment: I don't know vline nor tic.

Comment: @MERose The line `ggplot(data=ChickWeight, aes(ChickWeight$Time)) geom_histogram(binwidth=1)` should be `ggplot(data=ChickWeight, aes(ChickWeight$Time)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)`.  You are missing a `+` sign.  This is for the first code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to combine `pretty()` and `max()` as the `breaks=` values to set additional tick at maximal value.If function `pretty()` will produce values larger than maximal value those values will not be shown due to subsetting.

```
ggplot(data=ChickWeight, aes(Time)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1)+ 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(pretty(ChickWeight$Time)[pretty(ChickWeight$Time)<max(ChickWeight$Time)],max(ChickWeight$Time)))
```

[image]

Comment: `pretty(ChickWeight$Time)` results for me in `[1]  0  5 10 15 20 25`. That's not what I want, because it indicates that there are values above the actual maximum.

Comment: @MERose Updated my answer to ensure that values above maximal are discarded.